# Error 1001, can't find an actually present .manifest c# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, custom-action, merge-module

I'm trying to make a merge module of one versioning of one fully functional aplication, this version with modifications also is fully tested, at least the proyect itself, because, for some reason, even if i expressedly add the file, the .manifest can't be find by the installer and rollback all the instalation with this error:

[image: The error message with more detail, is the same Error:1001 than just before but with details]

Translating it to non-spanish speakers:

"Error 1001. Exception during the phase of instalation of returning to the original state. This exception will be omited and will continue to the original state. However, can be than the computer doesn't recover the initial state until you are already completed this phase. --> The dictionary savedState do not contain the values waited and can be damag..."

Not without a smile i remember i just can install it before add the inclusionActionList to the module custom action editor, but then, where can be the mistake if it was this inclution list.

Request for clarification, coments or constructive questions or cheer up wishes would be apreciated as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i just find the answer moments after i place the question, must say, hopefully somebody would be usefull someday.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, for this case i just found it

It was the complet ausence of the atribute "Custom Action" in the Properties of the Custom Actions, it must be something like this:

/deploymentManifestLocation="[TARGETDIR]\The Name of the Folder of your App\The name of your VSTO File.vsto"

That will do

¡Cheers!